# XSL padding to the longest field length

Tags: c#, xslt, exslt

I have an XSL file which has a for-each loop in it and I am using an EXSLT processor to give some added functionality (namely the string padding).

what I want to be able to do is pad out all fields so they are the length of the longest record for that field. For example, for each name to be as long as the longest name, and then for each record number to be padded as long as the longest record number.

Hope I have explained this okay.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="maxLength">
  <xsl:for-each select="name">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:if test="postion() = last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: This seems to give me everything I need without having to go down the XSLT 2.0 route.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="vMaxLengthIds">
        <xsl:for-each select="/table/tr[1]/*">
            <xsl:variable name="vPosition" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/table/tr/*[$vPosition]">
                <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" data-type="number" />
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('|',generate-id(),'|')" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vMaxLength"
                  select="/table/tr/*[contains(
                                         $vMaxLengthIds,
                                         concat('|',generate-id(),'|'))]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vPaddingMask"
                  select="'                                                '"/>
    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="td">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="th">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text> + </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tr/*/text()">
        <xsl:variable name="vPosition"
                      select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)"/>
        <xsl:value-of
             select="concat(
                        .,
                        substring(
                           $vPaddingMask,
                           1,
                           string-length(
                              $vMaxLength[count(preceding-sibling::*)
                                          = $vPosition])
                           - string-length()))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>June</td>
        <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>2011</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```
Day + Month    + Year + 
1   | January  | 2011 | 
31  | June     | 2011 | 
11  | February | 2011 |
```

Answer (score 1):

With C# you could move to an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XQSharp and then you can easily find the maximum length of your items and use a function like http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-string-to-length.html to pad them.
If you want to do it with XSLT 1.0 and EXSLT then use http://www.exslt.org/math/functions/max/index.html to find the maximum and use a solution in http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/padding.html to pad.

Comment: I will give the links a go and see how I get on... Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @Martin Do you know how can I use functions from xsltfunctions.com? I tried to copy and paste them inside my .xsl but don't work. Probably because I don't know where to put it. Maybe have I to download all this file http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xsl and include in my .xsl in some way? Thanks!

Comment: bluish, you should be able to include or import the file in your XSLT stylesheet, as long as you use an XSLT 2.0 processor (like Saxon 9 or like AltovaXML Tools) as that is XSLT 2.0 code. Of course including/importing over HTTP is not efficient so you should download the file once and then include/import a local copy. You could also copy/paste a single function from the web site into your stylesheet, you will need to make sure to define the namespaces `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and `xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: @Martin Thanks, you're very kind. I tried all you wrote but doesn't work, even if I try with a simple function inside my .xsl. It says "Namespace xxxx does not contain any functions". I'm not using Saxon etc. but Firefox and IE. Tell me if it's better to post a new question.

Comment: bluish, the function library works with XSLT 2.0 processors only, no browser supports that version of XSLT, they all only support XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Martin ...it's what I was afraid of. What a pity... I'll try a workaround, maybe Tomalak's answer. Thank you very much!!